# Como usar INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada event e outra chamada category preciso contar  quantidade de categorias vinda da `event->category_id`, mas preciso que a db entenda e e leia a category.

```
TABELAS **event** |**Category_id** ||     TABELA ||**Category** ------- 
                                   ||
 ||     title     |  2             ||               name 
 ||     desc      |  3             ||               color
```

---

Já tentei desta maneira.

```
 SELECT * as event,SELECT COUNT(*) as total from".self::$tablename." 
 GROUP BY category_id INNER JOIN category ON category.id = category.category.id  ";
```

Alguém pode ajudar ?

Comment: Cara, ta dificil entender o que você precisa fazer. Explique melhor o problema. Mostre como esta a modelagem e o relacionamento das tabelas, como é o select que você precisa.

Comment: eu tenho 2 querys - SELECT title,description,category_id from event by id;
                   outra    SELECT name color icon  from category by id ;
preciso entrar por category  pegar as cores nomes etc  e ao mesmo tempo quero pegar a category_id da SELECT event e contar as categorias cadastradas !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não falou o que é esse `self::$tableName`.. que tabela é essa? event? category?

Você quer contar a quantidade de categorias na tabela event, mas também selecionar o valor correspondente na tabela category? Isso foi o que eu entendi. Vamos lá:

```
Tabela event:
+--------------+-------------+
| nome         | category_id |
+--------------+-------------+
| arroz        |      1      |
+--------------+-------------+
| patolino     |      1      |
+--------------+-------------+
| chinelo sujo |      2      |
+--------------+-------------+

Tabela category:
+----+----------------+------+
| id |      title     | desc |
+----+----------------+------+
| 1  |  Categoria UM  | nada |
+----+----------------+------+
| 2  | Categoria DOIS | ola  |
+----+----------------+------+
```

Você pode usar essa query:

```
SELECT category.*,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event WHERE category_id = category.id) as total
FROM category
```

O resultado seria:

```
+----+----------------+------+-------+
| id |      title     | desc | total |
+----+----------------+------+-------+
| 1  |  Categoria UM  | nada |   2   |
+----+----------------+------+-------+
| 2  | Categoria DOIS | ola  |   1   |
+----+----------------+------+-------+
```

Comment: exatamente isso agradeço ! Obrigado resolvido!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer fazer um `SELECT` com um `JOIN` entre sua tabela de eventos e categorias.

Acho que isso resolve:

```
SELECT
  e.title AS event_title,
  e.description AS event_description,
  c.id AS event_category_id,
  c.name AS event_category_name,
  c.color AS event_category_color,
  c.icon AS event_category_icon
FROM event e 
  INNER JOIN category c ON
    c.id = e.category_id
```

Pronto, no mesmo `SELECT` você esta pegando tanto os dados do evento quanto da categoria dele.

Eu só não entendi a parte do total de categorias, você ainda quer apresentar o total de categorias cadastradas no mesmo `SELECT`?

Se for isso, não faz muito sentido. Seria melhor fazer outro `SELECT` fazendo um `COUNT` das categorias.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM category
```

---

### UPDATE

Bom, não faz sentido pois com esse `SELECT` trazendo eventos e categorias juntos nós estamos buscando no banco sempre 1 evento e 1 categoria correspondente a ele por linha.

Se você quiser um `COUNT` de todos as suas categorias você tem a opção de colocar uma subquery no `SELECT` mandando ele trazer o `COUNT`, veja:

```
SELECT
  e.title AS event_title,
  e.description AS event_description,
  c.id AS event_category_id,
  c.name AS event_category_name,
  c.color AS event_category_color,
  c.icon AS event_category_icon,
  (SELECT COUNT(cc) FROM category cc) AS count_category
FROM event e 
  INNER JOIN category c ON
    c.id = e.category_id
```

Fazendo isso você vai executar a query `SELECT COUNT(cc) FROM category cc` para cada linha retornada com evento e categoria, ou seja, se o seu `SELECT` de eventos te trazer 10 linhas essa subquery será executada 10 vezes.

Você pode também tentar fazer via `LEFT JOIN` ou `RIGHT JOIN`, não sei se irá funcionar para ser sincero, mas mesmo assim você ainda teria de fazer o `GROUP BY` das outras colunas e em todas as linhas retornadas de evento e categoria iria vir o mesmo número de `COUNT`.

Comment: o inner join eu consegui , só não consegui colocar o count(*) junto ! explique porque nao faz sentido por favor ?